# Spacing between characters on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a label and I wish to increase the spacing between characters.

- I tried adding a space between each character, but this was too much
- Perhaps there is a font with large spacing between the letters?
- If all else fails, I am considering putting each character (only a size character code), into its own textbox.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to insert a half space, but I don't recall the exact command (option-spacebar?). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)) has a complete list of spaces you can use.

Another approach would be a UIWebView with the letter-spacing CSS attribute set.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off creating a custom view and using your `drawRect` routine to draw the text manually.  You can use [CFAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFAttributedString/Reference/reference.html) to hold your text along with kerning information.

Update: sounds like you can't actually use `CFAttributedString` to draw text on the iPhone.  You can still use your `drawRect` to draw the customized text, but it will take some more work to actually get your custom kerning to work.

Comment: "iPhone OS Note: While Core Foundation on iPhone OS contains CFAttributedString, there are no additions to the APIs in UIKit to add specific attributes such as font, style, or color, and there are no APIs to draw attributed strings."

Comment: Thanks, KHG - I didn't see that.  Updated my response.

Comment: That line is still in the CFAttributedString page but then the Core Text String Attributes Reference lists all the common attributes. I'm going to believe the latter.